# UWP how to change ListView binding Observable Colletion outside the page class

Tags: binding, win-universal-app, non-static

I have a Page, on which I have a list view and its item source is bound to a Observable Collection property, which is ofcourse non-static. 
My question is that how can I access or change that collection outside of the Page class on which that listview resides. 
I want to change that collection outside, because I wanna change or add new items to that ListView from other pages as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm solving this problem with a static Property in my App.xaml.cs.
So I can access my Repository/Collection from any Page I want.
Every time I navigate to the page, I'm going to access App.MyCollection through my binded property.

You can create a property where your getter would create a new ObervableCollection(App.MyCollection);
if the current private member is null.

App.xaml.cs

```
private static IEnumerable<OrderHistory> _orderHistory;
public static IEnumerable<OrderHistory> OrderHistory
{
   get
   {
       if (_orderHistory == null)
           _orderHistory = new ObservableCollection<OrderHistory>();
           return _orderHistory;
       }
   set
   {
       if (_orderHistory != value)
           _orderHistory = value;
       }
   }
}
```

CodeBehind.xaml.cs

```
private ObservableCollection<OrderHistory> _orderHistoryList;
public ObservableCollection<OrderHistory> OrderHistoryList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_orderHistoryList == null)
                _orderHistoryList = new ObservableCollection<OrderHistory>(App.WorkOrderHistory);
            return _orderHistoryList;
        }
    }
```

When you want to change something on the properties of the class in the list, then just access it in App.OrderHistory.

The only think you need to take care of is in your OrderHistory Class:

```
public class OrderHistory : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isAvailable;
    public bool IsAvailable {
        get
        {
            return _isAvailable;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_isAvailable != value)
            {
                _isAvailable = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting wht exactly are you proposing, can you clarify it with some code please? thanks. 
P.S : I tried making a static public property and assigned that private collection to it. And then I made changes to it, but changes only occur in that static property, and my ListView items are not being updated.

Comment: I edited the post. Please have a look if this helps you out.

Comment: thanks a lot it is easy to understand and it helped me :)